# How To Install HAXM For Android When All Requirements Are Met?

Tags: android, android-studio, hyper-v, haxm

I have installed Android Studio but I was unable to install HAXM. I followed all the instructions given over the internet, Blogs, YouTube and read some of the answers here on Stack Overflow but none of them helped me. I have disabled Hyper-V, Virtual Machine Platform, Windows Hypervisor Platform and Windows Sandbox.
[image: Windows Features]

I have also enabled Virtualization in the BIOS.
[image: Virtualization]

But due to some reason I can't install HAXM. I tried installing it through Android Studio, but it didn't work. I also tried to download it manually from the website, it still didn't work. This is what I get (given in Image below)

[image: HAXM Installation]

Please could someone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have Windows 11, and i'm resolved this problem just set 0 in parameter "EnableVirtualizationBasedSecurity" in "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\DeviceGuard" branch. You also need to disable kernel isolation in "Windows Defender"

Comment: How do i enter "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\DeviceGuard" branch?

Comment: For Windows -> run regedit with administrator rights and open branches step by step until you reach folder "DeviceGuard". Then in right side window set value 0 for "EnableVirtualizationBasedSecurity" paremeter

Comment: Should i restart the PC after setting the value to 0?

Comment: Yes. Сomputer needs to be restarted

Answer (score 0):

> try going to bios and look for intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x) then Enable and try to install HAXM again

Comment: Hey I actually did that. I went to the BIOS and Enabled Virtualization but it still didn't work